# Insert JSON into an existing MongoDB collection

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I understood my mistake :) Thanks guys.
I have one more Question, suppose i have multiple documents with the below structure in "Customer" collection.

```
{
    "customerId":100,
    "FirstName":"xyz",
    "lastname":"pqr",
    "address":[
       {
          "house":44,
          "city":"Delhi",
          "country":"india"
       }
    ],
    "employer":[
       {
          "cmpName":"ABC",
          "type":"IT"
       }
    ]
```

### }

Now i have a JSON file as below:

```
{
    "customerId":100,
    "address":[
       {
          "house":99,
          "city":"MUMBAI",
          "country":"INDIA"
       }
    ]
 }
```

Can you please tell me how can i update the address array for customerId = 100 using the above JSON file in my c# code.

Please suggest.!

Thanks in advance :)

---

I am writing a C# (C sharp)(.Net) code to insert a JSON file in mongoDB. i have a jsonfile " records.JSON " which has multiple document in one single row in it,   like :

```
[{"customerId" : 100,"FirstName" : "xyz","lastname" : "pqr","address":[{"house": 44,"city" : "Delhi", "country" : "india"}],"employer":[{"cmpName" : "ABC","type" : "IT"}]}][{"customerId" : 101,"FirstName" : "LMN","lastname" : "GHI","address":[{"house": 90,"city" : "NewYork", "country" : "US"}],"employer":[{"cmpName" : "ABC","type" : "IT"}]}]
```

I need to insert this JSON file into an existing MongoDB collection.
So far I have the following code to connect and insert to mongodb :

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";    
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var server = client.GetServer();
            server.Connect();
            var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
 var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test_collection");
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"records.JSON");
            var bsonDoc = BsonArray.Parse (text);
            collection.Insert (bsonDoc);
        }
```

But this is giving me error as : " an array cannot be written to root level of BSON document" 
And if i parse BSON as : `var bsonDoc = BsonDocument.Parse (text);`
it gives me error as : `Cannot deserialize BsonDocumet from BsonType Array.`

Can anybody Please help me to understand How do i insert the JSON file into the mongoDB Collection. ??

Any help is appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CraigWilson  : please suggest !

Comment: @RobertStam : please suggest

Comment: The content of records.JSON is not a valid JSON document

Comment: @D.Rosado: Nice spot!

Comment: @D.Rosado hi I have added a new query in the thread ... Can you please suggest.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg  Please suggest on the new query

Answer (score 20):

Supposing that you are have a valid JSON file.

This is what you need to do, using the new [MongoDB.Driver 2.0:](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/)

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase("test");  

        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"records.JSON");

        var document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(text);
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test_collection");
        await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);

    }
```

I hope it works for you!

Regards.

Comment: Note: If text contains a list of records then the deserialize type should be an IEnumerable i.e. BsonSerializer.Deserialize<IList<BsonDocument>>

Answer (score 3):

As the previous answerer suggested, your JSON format is not valid.

If you pass in your JSON into a validator like this one: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ you'll see that the issue has to do with unecessary brackets shown here:

```
[
     {
        "customerId":100,
        "FirstName":"xyz",
        "lastname":"pqr",
        "address":[
           {
              "house":44,
              "city":"Delhi",
              "country":"india"
           }
        ],
        "employer":[
           {
              "cmpName":"ABC",
              "type":"IT"
           }
        ]
     }
  ][ <-------------------- Delete these brackets
     {
        "customerId":101,
        "FirstName":"LMN",
        "lastname":"GHI",
        "address":[
           {
              "house":90,
              "city":"NewYork",
              "country":"US"
           }
        ],
        "employer":[
           {
              "cmpName":"ABC",
              "type":"IT"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
```